# proxyPass working for browser but not for network request

Tags: node.js, apache

I have used ProxyPass for the node app in apache server. Now when I call the url with the browser then I get response `GET / 200 206.324 ms - 14` but when the same url hit by another server which send data via `POST` over the same url then I got `POST / 404 8.154 ms - 140` response.

ProxyPass I have set is like `"ProxyPass /myapi http://localhost:3000"`

Please let me know if I am missing something.

I have even changed `localhost` to `my site domain` in proxypass but still issue is same, we can access it via browser but not from Network request.

Service provide whitelisted the IPs which server uses for triggering the url.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, I am wondering if /myapi just doesn't have a POST handler. Are you using express? Can you please post your node.js code for the routes of your API?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a problem with server that it was allowing to hit post data only by some `whitelisted IPs`. So for accessing `port 3000` of my app service provider given access to `IP ranges`which 3rd party server uses for sending post data.

One more thing I did is set proxyPass like this

```
ProxyPass /myapi http://mysite:3000/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://mysite:3000/
```

also set `mysite` as a host in node app.

I was also missing to capture `post` in express due to this I was getting error 404. Since data is sent via post from another server then I need to capture it in post.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer. You have stated wrong issue in your question. I have flagged this answer.

Comment: Its not about my answer is correct or not. Its about marking your own low quality answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

The ProxyPass needs to end with a slash, also write ProxyPassReverse.

Just make the following change:

```
ProxyPass /myapi http://localhost:3000/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

[Reference Link](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/setup-node-js-with-apache-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04-for-production/)

Comment: There must be some other configuration error. Kindly post apache conf also.

Comment: slash not an issue in this.

Comment: Kindly remove slash from your code and then check if its an issue or not.

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar I have raised in need of moderator intervention for this.